# XPages servlet could not access Other Classes

Tags: xpages

I have written a servlet using this tutorial from [a Chinese developer works article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/lotus/xpage-servlet/index.html)

This servlet works fine for Helloworld printing but if a write a class and try to access that from the servlet doGet I get Error 500.

My servlet Class and ServletFactory is same as in the Above My Reference Link

Comment: I could access the same from void init() what does that means why cant i do that from doGet()?

Answer (score 0):

Your own classes have to implement the IServletFactory interface, too. Also you have to define your class name (with whole package name) in the Web-Inf/META_INF/services/com.ibm.xsp.adapter.servletFactory file.

Just add a line like this:

com.myclasses.MyClass